# How to invoke @Service from another project with REST call in Spring?

Tags: spring, rest

I need to use @Service from another Spring project. I will need a REST call to invoke it but how am I suppose to do it?
This is the service:

```
@Service
public class LocationsService implements ILocationsService {
private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("LocationsService");

private final ILocationRepository locationRepository;
private final IEvseRepository evseRepository;
private final IConnectorRepository connectorRepository;

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Autowired
public LocationsService(ILocationRepository locationRepository, IEvseRepository evseRepository, IConnectorRepository connectorRepository, EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.locationRepository = locationRepository;
    this.evseRepository = evseRepository;
    this.connectorRepository = connectorRepository;
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}

public Location getLocation(String countryCode, String partyId, String id) {
    return locationRepository.findByCountryCodeAndPartyIdAndId(countryCode, partyId, id);
}

public Location deleteLocation(String countryCode, String partyId, String id) {
    Location location = locationRepository.findByCountryCodeAndPartyIdAndId(countryCode, partyId, id);

    if (location == null) {
        logger.info("Location does not exist.");
        return null;
    }

    locationRepository.deleteById(location.getLocId());

    return location;
}
```

I need to call the service in this controller. The controller is in a different project:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/locations", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Api(tags = "Locations management")
public class LocationController {

    @Autowired
    private LocationsService locationsService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET , produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Get Locations", notes = "Get locations", nickname = "getLocations",
            authorizations = @Authorization(value = "Bearer"))
    public ResponseEntity<List<LocationDto>> getLocations() {

        List<LocationDto> locations = new ArrayList<>();

        return new ResponseEntity<>(locations, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I searched for solutions but found nothing helpful and will appreciate any help.
Thank you!

Comment: `RestTemplate`?

Comment: Do you want to make a REST call to `LocationsService`? It doesn't look a like a REST service. As your code shows, you are autowiring `LocationsService` in your controller, you might want to add the jar containing the `LocationsService` as dependency in your project and use it.